# Why My jdl file is generating domains with error in code?

Tags: jhipster, jdl

Hi I m using JHipster and doing some training in the jdl,

so while I generated a entity model from my jdl I got some code scaffolding errors, is this due to an error in my JDL or it is a issue in JHipster generator

```
entity Club{
    federation String,
    nomClub String,
    dateFondation LocalDate
}

entity Boxeur {
    nom String,
    prenom String,
    dateNaissance LocalDate,
    lieuNaissance String,
    dateInscription LocalDate
}

entity Entraineur{
    nom String,
    prenom String,
    dateNaissance LocalDate,
    lieuNaissance String,
    president Boolean
}
enum LieuSeance {
    SALLE,
    STADE,
    MONTAGNE,
    AUTRE
}

entity TypeSeance{
    typeSeance TypeSeance0
}
enum TypeSeance0 {
    COMPETITION,
    SPARRING,
    ENDURANCE,
    STREATCHING,
    TECHNIQUE,
    PHYSIQUE,
    ENTRETIEN,
    AUTRE
}

entity Seance{
    titre String,
    detail String,
    dateSeance LocalDate,
    lieu LieuSeance
}

entity Payement{
    montant Long,
    datePayement LocalDate
}

relationship OneToMany{
    Entraineur{seances(titre)} to Seance{entreneur(nom)},
    Boxeur{versement} to Payement,
    TypeSeance to Seance
}
relationship OneToOne{
   Club{president(nom)} to Entraineur
}
relationship ManyToMany{
    Seance{participants(nom)} to Boxeur{assistes(titre)}
}
paginate all with pagination

dto * with mapstruct

service all with serviceImpl
```

the error is in the Seance.Java where add and remove participants got errors in scafolding like in the picture below

[image: titre and S() are scaffolding error]

Did I make a mistake in my JDL file so I got this scafolding errors
Thanks you

I created an issue in [JHipster](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/9212)

Comment: If you did not change anything in code, it's a bug in generator that you should report on github.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou I did not change anything in code norin jhipster this is the first time generation, thx I will report in github

Comment: [issue created](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/9212)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue Corrected in new release
for more info visit github issue [tracker](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/9202)